# can not exit from iterate in wso2 esb

Tags: loops, wso2, exit

I am new to wso2 esb and now I have trouble with iterate mediator.
I used iterate in my code and send desired value to an endpoint but Unfortunately I can not exit from iterator.
here is my code

```
<iterate preservePayload="true"
              attachPath="//csv-set"
              expression="//csv-set/searchGuestIdentity"
              sequential="true">
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <xslt key="gov:/xmltocsv.xsl"/>
              <xslt key="gov:/new8.xsl"/>
              <xslt key="gov:/RemoveXMLdeclaration.xsl"/>
              <send>
                 <endpoint>
                    <http format="soap11"
                          method="GET"
                          uri-template="http://myendpoint/services/GuestIdentityService"/>
                 </endpoint>
              </send>
              <log level="full"/>
           </sequence>
        </target>
     </iterate>
     <log>
        <property name="log" value="end of iterate"/>
     </log>
```

I can not see the log after iterate.
can any one help me and say why I can not exit from iterator?
also when I send value to endpoint, how can I see the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Call mediator instead of send mediator and set yes for call mediator. Then you can use response mediator in end of your sequence to see the value of property in the log mediator

Comment: thanks for your reply Mehrnoosh. where should I put yes for call? can you give me an example?

Comment: There is an option in Call mediator for blocking call, set it to true. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Call+Mediator . If you put respond mediator in the insequence after call mediator, it would be fine, otherwise (if you want to flow request to outsequence put loopback mediator after call mediator )

Answer (score 2):

I realize the question was asked a long time ago, but maybe someone might need an answer.

Try to use parameter "continueParent" set to "true" in Iterate mediator:

```
<iterate preservePayload="true"
              continueParent="true"
              attachPath="//csv-set"
              expression="//csv-set/searchGuestIdentity"
              sequential="true">
```

According to wso2 documentation this parameter is used to specify whether the original message should be preserved or not. Possible values are as follows.

- True - If this is selected, the original message will be preserved.
- False - If this is selected, the original message will be discarded. This is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

When you use send mediator inside the iterator, response will come to out sequence. There you can use aggregate mediator[1] to aggregate the responses. You can find an example here[2]. Instead of send mediator ,if you use call mediator[3][4] responses will come to in sequence it self and rest of the logic will get executed.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Aggregate+Mediator

[2] http://shriwithjava.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-use-iterator-mediator-in-wso2-esb.html

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Call+Mediator

[4] https://medium.com/@pubududp/wso2-esb-how-to-use-call-mediator-457f2b387b94#.iu53akgyr

Comment: I used aggregate in the following of my code. my problem is that why I can not see this log:  <property name="log" value="end of iterate"/> Do you know why?

Comment: even when I use call mediator, I can not see this log " <property name="log" value="end of iterate"/>"